# JSON IF Blank IF Not Blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, form-formatting

I am trying to update SharePoint List Form in SharePoint Online so that when a Single Line text field is blank the Header will display a specific message and color but if there is any data in the Single Line Text field it will display a different message and color.

Below is the JSON script I tried but it's not working:

```
{
    "debugmode": "true",
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if([$Question] == '', 'ms-bgColor-redDark', ifno([$Question] == '', 'ms-bgColor-greenDark')"
    },
    "style": {
        "width": "99%",
        "border-top-width": "0px",
        "border-bottom-width": "1px",
        "border-left-width": "0px",
        "border-right-width": "0px",
        "border-style": "solid",
        "margin-bottom": "16px"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "align-items": "center"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "Bug",
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular  ms-fontColor-black",
                        "title": "Question"
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "flex": "none",
                        "padding": "0px",
                        "padding-left": "0px",
                        "height": "36px"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-black ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
            },
            "style": {
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "width": "100%",
                "text-align": "left",
                "padding": "21px 12px",
                "overflow": "hidden"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "=if ([$Question] == '', 'Complete the QA Frequently Asked Questions form below. Select the Category that most closely matches the question or select Other:', 'See Question Below')"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for `if` function is like:

```
if(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

---

Use below JSON to customize the header:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if([$Question] == '', 'ms-bgColor-redDark', 'ms-bgColor-greenDark')"
    },
    "style": {
        "width": "99%",
        "border-top-width": "0px",
        "border-bottom-width": "1px",
        "border-left-width": "0px",
        "border-right-width": "0px",
        "border-style": "solid",
        "margin-bottom": "16px"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "align-items": "center"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "Bug",
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular  ms-fontColor-black",
                        "title": "Question"
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "flex": "none",
                        "padding": "0px",
                        "padding-left": "0px",
                        "height": "36px"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-black ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
            },
            "style": {
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "width": "100%",
                "text-align": "left",
                "padding": "21px 12px",
                "overflow": "hidden"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "=if([$Question] == '', 'Complete the QA Frequently Asked Questions form below. Select the Category that most closely matches the question or select Other:', 'See Question Below')"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Documentation**: [Configure the list form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration)

---

**Update from comments**:

You have to use the **internal name** of column in JSON formatting. So, use `[$Title]` instead of `[$Question]` in JSON at all the places. You can get the exact internal name of any of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried the updated code but the Header text does not change when the Question field has data. I am not sure if the IF field is blank code ("txtContent": "=if([$Question] == '') is working or if something else is causing it to not work properly. Any additional help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question column is of type "single line of text" right? You can also try the condition like: `=if([$Question], 'ms-bgColor-greenDark', 'ms-bgColor-redDark')`

Comment: Yes, it is a single text field. It is the Title field renamed to Question. When I use the above condition the result defaults to the false or the second condition, so if the field is blank or has data it will be red, if I use the original condition (=if([$Question] == '') then it defaults to green for both blank and if there is data.

Comment: You have to use the **internal name** of column in JSON formatting. So, use `[$Title]` instead of `[$Question]` in JSON at all the places.

Comment: Ganesh you are a lifesaver, thank you so much. I can't believe I forgot that JSON requires internal field names. Thanks again.